# Sendmail Host unknown error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, sendmail, actionmailer

I am trying to a send mail using sendmail. But the mail does not get delievered. 
In the `/var/mail/root` I get this error

```
   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<noreply@xxxxx.com>
    (reason: 550 Host unknown)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
550 5.1.2 <noreply@xxxxx.com>... Host unknown (Name server: xxxxx.com: host not found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure Sendmail? Here is a ubuntu guide http://developernote.com/2012/07/how-i-configured-sendmail-for-php-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/ or google "install sendmail"

Answer (score 0):

Can you get `MX` or `A` DNS records of xxxxx.com?

NO => it is not Sendmail's fault.

A "non sendmail" test:

```
dig MX xxxxx.com
```

Comment: Thanks, but i figured if I give from: "xxxxx.com" in mailer.rb file, it works. But if i give noreply@xxxxx.com , it does not work and ends up giving 550 unknown host error

Comment: i did `dig MX xxxxx.com` .. how do i know if sendmail is working fine?